# Add lead to Campaign through the use of a unique code entered on Website

Tags: campaign, web2lead, massemailmessage, form, pardot

I am using Salesforce /Pardot for Marketing purposes. I have a requirement where I would like to send mass letters to Leads, inviting them to an Event. On this letter I have a unique random number generated in Salesforce. (All of the above has been completed).

On this letter, I would like to prompt people to go to my Website and key in the random number which they received on the letter. If the number matches a record in Salesforce (/Pardot?), I would like to say 'Congrats...' and add them to a campaign in SF (or Pardot).

Anyone have any ideas on how to go about this? I have tried using Pardot Forms /SF Web-to-Lead forms but could not find a way to meet the requirement.